# Querying MS SQL from PostgreSQL (FDW)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, tds-fdw

I need to query a specific table that is in MS SQL server using my PostgreSQL 9.3 running in Windows. I did some research and found a FDW that would make it possible (tds_fdw), but the instructions to build it are valid only for linux.

I could build it in a linux dist, but would it work on windows?

If this is not possible, is there any other idea on how to do it? I have full access on both servers and the MS SQL table will need only to be read once a day (and the amount of lines is quite small, so performance is not an issue).

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot compile it on Linux then copy to Windows. Most likely nobody's done the work required to make sure it works on Windows, document how to compile it on Windows or prepare binary distributions, etc.

Comment: well since you need to do it just once a day why not simply dump and import? And really why do you need two databases from different vendors?

Comment: I've given up on tds_fdw and started looking into ogr_fdw (it is supposed to be used for GIS applications, but it does have a ODBC connector). It kinda works, I could map a table in the MS SQL but now I am facing issues with data types that are incompatible.. Maybe I will run the dump and import method(but even though I have SA for the MSSQL, I don't want to create too much there, it is not "my server")